# How to set a value to a view when it is passed as a parameter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

```html
Picasso.with(Settings_Activity.this).load(R.drawable.nopic).placeholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nopic))
  .resize(300, 300).into(profilePic);
```

this is a code of which is used with Picasso library in that we are passing image view as a parameter then the specific image is loaded in that view,similarly i want to pass a linear layout as parameter then there will be a background image which will be loaded into it,how can i do that ,need help

Comment: Do you need any help from me?
If my answer solve your problem, accept my answer.!

Comment: i have updated my answer..Now check and accept. If you need still help, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to set Target .eg.

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load("http://url").into(target);
```

Here is Target:

```
 private Target target = new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
            setBackgroundV16Plus(content, bitmap);
        } else {
            setBackgroundV16Minus(content, bitmap);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

    }
};
```

Here are other two methods :

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private void setBackgroundV16Plus(View view, Bitmap bitmap) {
    view.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap));

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void setBackgroundV16Minus(View view, Bitmap bitmap) {
    view.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
}
```

and content is your view (Linear layout, FrameLayout etc.)

```
private View content;
```

Hopping, it will solve your problem :)

<<-------------- UPDATE------------>>

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    private Target target = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                setBackgroundV16Plus(content, bitmap);
            } else {
                setBackgroundV16Minus(content, bitmap);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        }
    };
    private LinearLayout content;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
        content=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.content);
        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load("http://url").into(target);

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private void setBackgroundV16Plus(View view, Bitmap bitmap) {
        view.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap));

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void setBackgroundV16Minus(View view, Bitmap bitmap) {
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain what is content and what is target please

Comment: content is view (in your case it can be linearlayout).

Comment: i still could'nt figure out how its done since im a beginner.need more detailed answer for me,please

Comment: NOTE: You can pass URL or drawable in load method.